# How to combine multiple probabilities into an overall probability?

Tags: probability, bayesian

Imagine a hypothetical situation: According to an electoral poll, presidential candidate A has 65% of votes among women;
This same pool showed, in the state stratification, that this candidate has 40% of the votes in California;
When stratified by salary range, this candidate has 70% of the votes among those earning between \$80,000 and \$100,000.

How to determine the probability that Maria, a woman, California resident with a salary between \$80,000 and \$100,000, will vote for Candidate A?

My first thought was to use Bayes' theorem, but this problem seems a little different. I believe that with Bayes' theorem I would be able to calculate the probability that a random person be a woman, Californian, and in this salary range.

Note that if one of these factors is either 100% or 0%, the overall probability must be 100% or 0%.
(For example, if 100% of women vote for Candidate A, that in itself guarantees that Maria will vote for Candidate A)

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean by "overall probability". If you mean either the joint probability or the probability of the union then the marginal probabilities alone don't tell you how to combine them. If the events are independent, then just multiply them together for the joint probability. For the union also consider the [IE principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) assuming independence. You could also consider the [Fréchet inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_inequalities) or similar if independence is not assumed.

Comment: Overall probability is, in the given example, the odds o someone that is both Californian, woman and are in the \$80k-\$100k salary range vote for candidate A. I have the probability of the isolated stratifications and would like to calculate the probability of knowing these 3 factors together. The product does not make sense. For this example, would be .4 x .7 x .65, which would be only 18%. It's not exactly about events, but data stratifications.